# How to combine this document keypress and button click events

Tags: jquery, onclick, keypress

I can find plenty of combining keypress and click events. Though I cannot find one that combines one that has a keypress on the document and a click event on a link.

How do I shorten this code? Keeping in mind I don't want to add a click event to the entire document and want to avoid repeating the code as I have.

*My code makes it so if you press the 'S' key on the keyboard the fullscreen comes up or you can press the Search button. Both will do the same function.*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(searchstock) {
    if(searchstock.which == 83) {
      $('#header-bar').toggleClass('displaysearch');
      setTimeout(
        function()
        {
          $('#ccstocknum').select();
        }, 75);
    }
  });
  $("#searchbtn a").on("click", function(){
    $('#header-bar').toggleClass('displaysearch');
    setTimeout(
      function()
      {
        $('#ccstocknum').select();
      }, 75);
  });
});
```

```css
#header-bar {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
#header-bar.displaysearch { display: block; }
#header-bar h1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
p.strong { font-weight: bold !important; }
#searchbtn { float: left; width: 100%; }
#searchbtn a { padding: 10px; background: grey; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="strong">Press S on the keyboard to get the fullscreen image</p>
<p>Alternatively you can press the following link</p>
<div id="searchbtn">
  <a href="#">Search</a>
</div>
<div id="header-bar">
  <h1>Full Screen</h1>
  <input type="number" id="ccstocknum" />
</div>
```

My thoughts are if I can change:

`if(searchstock.which == 83) {`

To something like:

`if(searchstock.which == 83) or $('#searchbtn a').on("click", function() {`

Though obviously that doens't work ^_^

Thank you in advance :-)

**Update**
Keypress was having issues with 'S' or single keys in Chrome. So I changed it to keydown. Works a treat :-)

Comment: `if(searchstock.which == 83, 115)` doesn't do what you probably think it does

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I notice this breaks the actual key that is pressed. I removed the 115 and use only 83 now and replaced keypress with keydown as I was having issues with 's' key not working in chrome. Thank you for the headsup :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the code in a function and call it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(searchstock) {
    if(searchstock.which == 83, 115) {
      searchstock();
    }
  });
  $("#searchbtn a").on("click", function(){
    searchstock();
  });
});
function searchstock(){
   $('#header-bar').toggleClass('displaysearch');
    setTimeout(
      function()
      {
        $('#ccstocknum').select();
      }, 75);
}
```

```css
#header-bar {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
#header-bar.displaysearch { display: block; }
#header-bar h1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
p.strong { font-weight: bold !important; }
#searchbtn { float: left; width: 100%; }
#searchbtn a { padding: 10px; background: grey; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="strong">Press S on the keyboard to get the fullscreen image</p>
<p>Alternatively you can press the following link</p>
<div id="searchbtn">
  <a href="#">Search</a>
</div>
<div id="header-bar">
  <h1>Full Screen</h1>
  <input type="number" id="ccstocknum" />
</div>
```

You can also use `.on()` this way

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "body" ).on({
    click: function(e) {
    if((e.target.tagName === 'A') && (e.target.parentNode.id === 'searchbtn'))
      searchstock();
    },
    keypress: function(e) {
      if((e.which == 83) || (e.which ==115)) {
        searchstock();
      }
    }
  });
});
function searchstock(){
   $('#header-bar').toggleClass('displaysearch');
    setTimeout(
      function()
      {
        $('#ccstocknum').select();
      }, 75);
}
```

```css
#header-bar {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
#header-bar.displaysearch { display: block; }
#header-bar h1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
p.strong { font-weight: bold !important; }
#searchbtn { float: left; width: 100%; }
#searchbtn a { padding: 10px; background: grey; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="strong">Press S on the keyboard to get the fullscreen image</p>
<p>Alternatively you can press the following link</p>
<div id="searchbtn">
  <a href="#">Search</a>
</div>
<div id="header-bar">
  <h1>Full Screen</h1>
  <input type="number" id="ccstocknum" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Ram_Segev thank you very much. Exactly what I needed and cheers for the alternative binding of the events to the body tag. The function method works great. This will be very useful as my code gets bigger for both of these binds.

Comment: jQuery `bind()` is deprecated

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for the comment, i've update my answer